# Automate the Onclick screen popup

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, onclick

Using IE I have automated a site but now after everything, I got stuck with a form which throws a dialogue box "Message from Webpage" Ok or Cancel.

[Dialogue Box Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhtjg.png)

Brower's HTML inscpect :

```
<div class="formbuttons">

<input name="Deactivate" class="formsubmit deactivate" id="ButtonDeactivate" 
style="width: 160px;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to 
deactivate the feature?');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceBody$ButtonDeactivate&quot;,&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;
&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" type="submit" value="Deactivate">

</div>
```

The methods I have tried :

**1. By removing the onclick from html but it didn't help though regular expression is actually removing it**

```
    [String] $body = "onclick=.*feature....."
    $ie.Document.body.innerHTML -replace "$body", ""
    $deactivate=$ie.document.getElementById("ButtonDeactivate")
    $deactivate.Click();
```

**2. By adding few statements as mentioned here ([Automating IE confirmation prompt with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173867/automating-ie-confirmation-prompt-with-powershell?rq=1))**

```
    $ie.document.forms | Select -First 1 | % { $_.submit() }
```

My only motive is to click on the OK popup button.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to query the Outer HTML property of the item to get the HTML code. Then all you have to do is replace the "confirm (*)" with "". After that you can set it back into the script and then click it.

```
$Script = $IE.document.getElementsByTagName("script").item(#----------Whatever Number it is)
$Script.outerHTML = $Script.outerHTML | % {if ($_ -like "return confirm*") {"return true;"} else {$_}}
$autotransbtn.Click()
```

Reference:

(1) [Automating JavaScript confirmation prompt in IE using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686136/automating-javascript-confirmation-prompt-in-ie-using-powershell)

(2) [internet explorer - Automating IE confirmation prompt with Powershell](https://www.oipapio.com/question-7192624)

Comment: Hi Deepak, Thanks for the quick reply. What's "script" and item here? I'm quite new to this. I tried using it by script tag but it gave an error.

Comment: It will be an object for your JS script. this is just an example. You can try to modify it based on your own requirement.

Comment: Just checked, my html is different from 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686136/automating-javascript-confirmation-prompt-in-ie-using-powershell). 
There the onclick calls a function but in my case its within the input tags.

**This is what I did but it still gives a prompt :**
`$Script = $ie.document.getElementById("ButtonDeactivate")`

`$Script.outerHTML = $Script.outerHTML | % {if ($_ -like "return confirm*") {"return Ok;"} else {$_}}`

`$Script.Click()`

I returned Ok instead of True as the prompt says Ok or Cancel in my case. Let me know if ou see an issue here. :)

Comment: Tried this too but it's not replacing when I'm trying to print output
`$Script = $ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_ButtonDeactivate")
        $tobereplaced = "confirm(*)"
        $Script.outerHTML = $Script.outerHTML | % {$_.replace("$tobereplaced","")}
        $scriptout = $Script.outerHTML
        Write-Host "$scriptout"`

Comment: Output received before the Ok / Cancel prompt was - 
`<input name="Deactivate" class="formsubmit deactivate" id="ButtonDeactivate" style="width: 160px;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to deac
tivate the feature?');" type="submit" value="Deactivate">`

Comment: It can be possible that script get stopped while popup is on the screen and script get hanged until you close the pop up manually. In that case, only possible way to use multiple threads and try to close the popup using another thread. If possible than try to download the Wasp library and make a test with it may help to solve this issue.

Comment: There is no any other solution available for this issue, if possible for you than you can try to use Selenium Web driver can be a work around for handling the popups.

Comment: Ok, will see that too.

Comment: @Rahul, Is there any status update for this issue? Did you find any work around? If you solved the issue than please try to post the answer and try to mark it as an answer. If issue still persist than let us know about that. we will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Tried multiple things but none helped. I am still trying.

Comment: Thanks for updating the status of the issue. I will again try to test the issue and try to check whether there is any other solution which can solve the issue or not. If I will get any solution than I will try to provide you. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks again Deepak :-)