# powershell click on internet explorer popup

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, powershell-remoting

I need to use PowerShell to hit close on this pop up window which appears when I open internet explorer. Hitting enter key also closes the pop up.
[image]

**What I've tried**

```
        [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
        [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")

        $ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
        $ie.visible = $true
        $ie.navigate('http://website/')
        while ($ie.busy) { Start-Sleep 3 }  
        [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("internet explorer")    
     
        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("{ENTER}");
       
        Start-Sleep 3
        $link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('Button') | where-object { $_.innerText -eq 'Simple Setup' }
        $link.click()
        Start-Sleep 2
        $ie.quit()
```

Comment: That is not a web page, it's a WIndows modal dialog. So, using IE COM on a dialog box is not a thing. You have to act on the modal dialog directly via UX/UI automation. ***Use sendkeys/selenium/AutoIt*** to Tab to the modal dialog, then send the enter key when you land on the button, or capture the Windows handle of the dialog and take action on that.

Comment: I agree with postanote's comment. It's an OS level window and you can't reach it using IE COM. You say hitting Enter key can close it, then you can try to use `SendKeys` to simulate the Enter key clicking. You can refer to [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1249976/sendkeys-method-in-powershell) about using `SendKeys` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

Others have run into this dialog and others, and, as stated, used Selenium, AutoIT, et., to deal with that; while others have tried different means.

[For Example:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173867/automating-ie-confirmation-prompt-with-powershell)

```
# using the process handle of that dialog
$ws = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$ld = (gps iex* | where {$_.MainWindowTitle }).id

if($ld.Count -gt 1)
{
  $ws.AppActivate($ld[1])
  $ws.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
}

# Using the WASP module 
# (note - though the code for this module is still available, the DLL is not. So, you have to compile that yourself.)
Import-Module WASP
while ($true) {
  [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(200) 
  $confirmation = Select-Window iexplore 
  if ($confirmation -ne $null) 
  {
    Select-ChildWindow  -Window $confirmation | 
    Select-Control -title "OK" -recurse | 
    Send-Click
  }
}
```

btw..

> "Hitting enter key also closes the pop up"

... that is because modal dialogs always take focus until they are dismissed.